# why only the last entry is returned with itemgetter and groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-keyword, python-itertools

I was wondering whether what the code below returns is expected?

I'm running this on Python 3.7.

I expected the "Expected" output but only the last entry for each group is returned as shown in "Actual".

```
import operator
import itertools

adict = {'a': 1, 'b':3, 'c': 1, 'd': 2, 'e': 3, 'f': 1}

dict((i, dict(v)) for i, v in itertools.groupby(adict.items(), operator.itemgetter(1)))
```

```
Expected Output: {1: {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'f':1}, 2: {'d': 2}, 3: {'b', 'e'} }

Actual : {1: {'f': 1}, 3: {'e': 3}, 2: {'d': 2}}
```

Comment: There is an inconsistency in your expected output

Comment: Anyway, why the nested dicts? why not `{1: ['a', 'c', 'f'], 2: ['d'], 3: ['b', 'e']}` which can be obtained quite trivially with `defultdict`?

Comment: Hi @DeepSpace  ,  I'm just getting familiar with itertools and operator functions and was going through examples and so encountered this issue.  here's the link https://riptutorial.com/python/example/923/operator-module

Comment: `itertools.group` works on **consecutive** keys... of which, you don't have any... and since a dictionary has unique keys, while you're building it you're replacing that group's keys with the last seen values for that key...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you break `dict((i, dict(v)) for i, v in itertools.groupby(adict.items(), operator.itemgetter(1)))` down it should be clear why only the last key-value pair is in the final dict:

```
for i, v in itertools.groupby(adict.items(), operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print(i, dict(v))
```

outputs

```
1 {'a': 1}
3 {'b': 3}
1 {'c': 1}
2 {'d': 2}
3 {'e': 3}
1 {'f': 1}
```

calling `dict` on each of these will overwrite the previously created dict with the same outer key.

It can be fixed by using [`defaultdict(dict)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) while making sure to `update` the existing inner dict with the new key-value pair:

```
from collections import defaultdict

adict = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 1, 'd': 2, 'e': 3, 'f': 1}

output = defaultdict(dict)
for i, v in adict.items():
    output[v][i] = v
print(output)
```

outputs

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {1: {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'f': 1}, 3: {'b': 3, 'e': 3}, 2: {'d': 2}})
```

You don't have to use `defaultdict`, but it saves an existence check:

```
adict = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 1, 'd': 2, 'e': 3, 'f': 1}

output = {}
for i, v in adict.items():
    if v in output:
        output[v][i] = v
    else:
        output[v] = {i: v}
print(output)
```

outputs

```
{1: {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'f': 1}, 3: {'b': 3, 'e': 3}, 2: {'d': 2}}
```

As Jon mentioned in the comments, this can also be remedied by sorting `adict.values` first by the same key (`operator.itemgetter(1)`):

```
dict((i, dict(v)) for i, v in itertools.groupby(sorted(adict.items(), key=itemgetter(1)), operator.itemgetter(1)))
```

This caveat is actually mentioned in `itertools.groupby` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> ... Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function.

Comment: Or if one *really* wants to use `itertools.groupby` then sort by the grouping key first so they're all consecutive, eg: `dict((i, dict(v)) for i, v in itertools.groupby(sorted(adict.items(), key=itemgetter(1)), operator.itemgetter(1)))`

Comment: @JonClements correct, this caveat is even in the docs (that the sequence should be sorted by the same key function passed to groupby). I'll add it

Comment: If you're using `defaultdict` though... just scrub the whole `itertools` stuff, just use `for i, v in adict.items(): output[v][i] = v`...

Comment: @JonClements Agreed

Comment: And if you're going to suggest not using `defaultdict` then `setdefault` is your friend and you can avoid the existence check by using: `for i, v in adict.items(): output.setdefault(v, {}).update(((i, v),))`

Comment: thanks very much @JonClements and DeepSpace  for the very granular explanations.  Appreciate it!